# matteodem:meteor-easy-search - Is there a way to search only and exactly the first 4 characters

Tags: meteor

Is there a way to make it search only (and exactly) the first 3 or 4 characters of field?

For example say I have 3,000 postcode districts (in the UK). I am trying to search for "E14", currently the results include anything with E14 in it e.g.

====>Search results from query

- DE14
- E14 (===> what I actually want)
- LE14
- ME14
- PE14
- SE14

============

I'm thinking I could add something to the createSearchIndex code:

```
EasySearch.createSearchIndex('postcodeDistricts', {
'collection'    :   PostcodeDistricts,
'field'         :   'postcodeDistrict',
'limit'         :   8
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the easy search package developers here. I know this question has already been resolved on Github, but I've actually seen this come up multiple times before, so maybe it'll help if I clarify some things here.

If you're not relying on elastic search, by default the package uses the mongo searcher. What this searcher does is look up documents with a regex like this:

```
{ '$regex' : '.*' + searchString + '.*', '$options' : 'i' }
```

With the `query` option, you have the option to effectively alter the regex passed into the query. So, changing the regex to something like `'^' + searchString` ends up matching all results with the content of `searchString` explicitly at the beginning, which is what OP wanted.

Hopefully we'll make this easier to do in the future, but for now that will work. Cheers :)

Answer (score 2):

Had a response on the Github page to this, for anyone else that may be interested:

https://github.com/matteodem/meteor-easy-search/issues/95

====== UPDATED FOLLOWING COMMENTS REGARDING POSTING THE SOLUTION:

Solution for me was to include a query as follows

```
EasySearch.createSearchIndex('collectionName', {

'collection': CollectionName,
'field': 'fieldName', //What you'd like to query
'limit': 8 //Default is 10,
//A query is what is required. The below worked for me
'query': function (searchString, opts) {
   var query = EasySearch.getSearch(this.use).defaultQuery(this, '^'+searchString);
   return query;
  }
})
```